# installing Percona XtraDB Cluster on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

So, a bit of explanation of the big picture: I am trying to get multiple PXC instances running on a single machine, replicating via Galera to each other. I am running Ubuntu Server 13.04 amd64 in a VirtualBox OSE virtual machine. I installed the Percona debian/ubuntu repository and installed percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.5, percona-xtrabackup, percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5, percona-xtradb-cluster-common-5.5, and percona-xtradb-cluster-galera-2.x from there. `mysqld --version` shows "mysqld Ver 5.5.33-55 for Linux on x86_64 (Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), wsrep_23.7.6.r3915)".

Once I had PXC installed, I set up a `/data/mysql` directory and several /etc/mysql/my.*.cnf`files, one for each node I intended to create.`my.galera1.cnf` looks like so:

```
[mysqld]
port = 5533
socket=/tmp/mysql.galera1.sock
datadir=/data/mysql/galera1
#basedir=/usr/bin
user=root
log_error=error.log
innodb_file_per_table

### galera-required settings ###
query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1

### wsrep basic settings ###
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name=boringname
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://localhost:5533,localhost:5534,localhost:5535
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
#wsrep_sst_auth=repluser:replpass
wsrep_node_name=node1
wsrep_node_address=localhost:5533

[mysql]
user=root
```

I then called `mysql_install_db --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.galera1.cnf` to initialize the data directory, followed by `mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.galera1.cnf --wsrep-new-cluster`. `mysqld_safe` prints the following to the screen:

> 130927 23:53:22 mysqld_safe Logging to '/data/mysql/galera1/error.log'.
>   130927 23:53:22 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /data/mysql/galera1
>   130927 23:53:22 mysqld_safe Skipping wsrep-recover for empty datadir: /data/mysql/galera1
>   130927 23:53:22 mysqld_safe Assigning 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1 to wsrep_start_position
>   130927 23:53:32 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /data/mysql/galera1/ubusrv1304-0.pid ended

and the following to `/data/mysql/galera1/error.log`:

> 130927 23:53:22 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /data/mysql/galera1
>   130927 23:53:22 mysqld_safe Skipping wsrep-recover for empty datadir: /data/mysql/galera1
>   130927 23:53:22 mysqld_safe Assigning 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1 to wsrep_start_position
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_start_position var submitted: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1'
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so'
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 2.7(r157) by Codership Oy  loaded succesfully.
>   130927 23:53:22 [Warning] WSREP: Could not open saved state file for reading: /data/mysql/galera1//grastate.dat
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Preallocating 134219048/134219048 bytes in '/data/mysql/galera1//galera.cache'...
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_host = localhost; base_port = 5533; cert.log_conflicts = no; gcache.dir = /data/mysql/galera1/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /data/mysql/galera1//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.size = 128M; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = NO; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = NO; replicator.causal_read_timeout = PT30S; replicator.commit_order = 3
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: -1, protocol version: -1
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: (e6e10868-27f9-11e3-85c4-2672bd9349a7, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:5533') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:5533
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: (e6e10868-27f9-11e3-85c4-2672bd9349a7, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:5533') multicast: , ttl: 1
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: PC version 0
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'boringname', peer ''
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Node e6e10868-27f9-11e3-85c4-2672bd9349a7 state prim
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,e6e10868-27f9-11e3-85c4-2672bd9349a7,1) memb {
>     e6e10868-27f9-11e3-85c4-2672bd9349a7,
>   } joined {
>   } left {
>   } partitioned {
>   })
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'boringname'
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete.
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Starting new group from scratch: e6e177a0-27f9-11e3-92e7-4b4286f53f4a
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: e6e17ffd-27f9-11e3-8c08-8b5bd34ddb16
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: e6e17ffd-27f9-11e3-8c08-8b5bd34ddb16
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: e6e17ffd-27f9-11e3-8c08-8b5bd34ddb16 from 0 (node1)
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
>     version    = 2,
>     component  = PRIMARY,
>     conf_id    = 0,
>     members    = 1/1 (joined/total),
>     act_id     = 0,
>     last_appl. = -1,
>     protocols  = 0/4/2 (gcs/repl/appl),
>     group UUID = e6e177a0-27f9-11e3-92e7-4b4286f53f4a
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [16, 16]
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Restored state OPEN -> JOINED (0)
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: e6e177a0-27f9-11e3-92e7-4b4286f53f4a:0, view# 1: Primary, number of nodes: 1, my index: 0, protocol version 2
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: SST complete, seqno: 0
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
>   130927 23:53:22 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
>   130927 23:53:22 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>   130927 23:53:22 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>   130927 23:53:22 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>   130927 23:53:22 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Member 0 (node1) synced with group.
>   130927 23:53:22 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINED -> SYNCED (TO: 0)
>   130927 23:53:22 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>   130927 23:53:22 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>   InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
>   InnoDB: a new database to be created!
>   130927 23:53:22  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
>   InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
>   130927 23:53:22  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
>   InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
>   InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
>   130927 23:53:22  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
>   InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
>   InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
>   InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
>   InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
>   InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
>   InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
>   InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
>   130927 23:53:22  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
>   130927 23:53:23 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.33-rel31.0 started; log sequence number 0
>   130927 23:53:23 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 98: Address already in use
>   130927 23:53:23 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 5533 ?
>   130927 23:53:23 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: Closing send monitor...
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: Closed send monitor.
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: terminating thread
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: joining thread
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closing backend
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closed
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: Received self-leave message.
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [0, 0]
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: Received SELF-LEAVE. Closing connection.
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: Shifting SYNCED -> CLOSED (TO: 0)
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: RECV thread exiting 0: Success
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: recv_thread() joined.
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: Closing replication queue.
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: Closing slave action queue.
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: Service disconnected.
>   130927 23:53:25 [Note] WSREP: rollbacker thread exiting
>   130927 23:53:26 [Note] WSREP: Some threads may fail to exit.
>   130927 23:53:26  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>   130927 23:53:27  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1597945
>   130927 23:53:27 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
>
> Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit
>   130927 23:53:32 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /data/mysql/galera1/ubusrv1304-0.pid ended

Seeing the error about binding to port 5533, I ran `netstat -anp | grep 5533`, but got no results, indicating (I think) that port 5533 has no process bound to it, in fact.

At some point previously, I somehow managed to get the server to at least stay up, and while I could connect to it from the mysql command line client, there was no command that didn't complain that there was no such command.

I am thoroughly baffled at what I'm doing wrong, so any help at all would be very welcome. Thank you, everyone, in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error was obvious:

```
130927 23:53:23 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 98: Address already in use
130927 23:53:23 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 5533 ?
130927 23:53:23 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Something else was already bound to that port. Usually this is another copy of the server.

Stop the other server before trying to restart it.

Comment: Ah yes, I noticed that, so I ran `netstat -anp | grep 5533`, with no results, so it does not appear that anything else is bound to the port. I'll update the question.